# How to load a page faster even multiple js files are specified in single page

Tags: javascript

I have more then 20 script files in my page. The page is not loading until all script files and css files completely loaded  when ever request made for this page.

please let me know any suggestions for loading this page very fast.

Comment: Don't put the scripts in the `head` section, put them right before `</body>`.

Comment: how much time it is taking now and how do you define very fast? There might be other things that is slowing down the page.

Comment: Minify and consolidate them into one css and one js file, load your js in <body> instead of <head>, check for redundancy, etc.

Comment: my page is not loading fully until all js files are executed. i want load the page first completely and then js files should be started executing. i placed my script files inside of body tag only.

Answer (score 1):

Put all your js files at the end of the page just before closing `</body>` tag. Also consider minifying your files and putting them into one single file - you minimise the number of requests from 20 to 1 which might help rapidly.

Comment: my page is not loading fully until all js files are executed. i want load the page first completely and then js files should be started executing.